# what php.ini does symfony2 cli-commands use?

Tags: php, symfony, ubuntu-14.04

I'm running a console command for symfony `sudo php app/console assetic:dump` and it is showing **Warnings** even though I specifically ignore Warnings on the php.ini for apache and for cli.
Is it using a different php.ini altogether?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do `sudo php -i` for a readout of your PHP settings, including the path to `php.ini`.

Comment: I forgot about this option :).
Indeed, it is using the /etc/php5/cli ini

Answer (score 2):

Run the following command:

```
php -i | grep .ini
```

and you will see the full path of the php.ini used by cli.

Don't use `sudo` when dumping assets as the owner of the created files will be "root" and the nginx/apache user will not be able to use them.

Comment: That is incorrect Udan, Apache only needs write access to cache and log. The rest can be accessed with read-only permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is probable that php used on the command line uses a different php.ini than php in apache.

Specifically in wamp server, php cli uses the php.ini in the `php` directory, and php as apache module uses php.ini situated in the `apache/bin` folder.